# Getting list of undefined functions in Python code

Tags: python, undefined, abstract-syntax-tree

Given Python code,

```
def foo():
  def bar():
    pass

  bar()

foo()
bar()
```

I'd like to get a list of functions which, if I execute the Python code, will result in a `NameError`.

In this example, the list should be `['bar']`, because it is not defined in the global scope and will cause an error when executed.

1. Executing the code in a loop, each time defining new functions, is not performant enough.
2. Currently I walk the AST tree, record all function definitions and all function calls, and subtract one from the other. This gives the wrong result in this case.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, can you elaborate a little more on what the expected output is?

Comment: do you have ast in hand? if you do, what makes you struggle?

Comment: @Matt the expected output is `['bar']` (second paragraph). My goal is to run the code with default functions for the missing ones.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I can parse the code, yes. I'd like to avoid rewriting the parts of the Python interpreter in Python :)

Comment: @user1071136 if you have ast in hand, that should be very easy. dfs for definition and try match symbol to the way down. sound easy intuitively. maybe you can provide a short example to point out what problem you encounter?

Comment: Are you looking for functions that are not defined in the global scope but are being used in it (i.e bar on the last line) or functions that are defined in some scope (i.e bar in the function scope of foo) but are not available in the global scope?

Comment: @Matt whatever raises a `NameError`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr the problem is that it's tricky to get it 100% correct, and I'd like to avoid having to maintain this code. Python evolves and I don't want to have to update it later. Context: this goes into production code which will see weird and contrived and insane Python programs.

Comment: You could use pyflakes and look specifically for the "undefined name" error: https://github.com/pyflakes/pyflakes/

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to write some static analyzer for python. maybe you are working on C, but i think it would be faster for me to show the idea only in python:

```
list_token = # you have tokenized the program now.

class Env:
    def __init__(self):
        self.env = set()
        self.super_env = None # this will point to Env instance

    def __contains__(self, key):
        if key in self.env:
            return True
        if self.sub_env is not None:
            return key in self.super_env

    def add(self, key):
        self.env.add(key)

topenv = Env()
currentenv = topenv

ret = [] # return list

for tok in list_token:
    if is_colon(tok):  # is ':', ie. enter a new scope
        newenv = Env()
        currentenv.super_env = newenv
        currentenv = newenv
    else if is_exiting(tok): # exit a scope
        currentenv = currentenv.super_env
    else if refing_symbol(tok):
        if tok not in currentenv: ret.add(tok)
    else if new_symbol(tok):
        currentenv.add(tok)
    else: pass
```

if you think this code is not enough, please point out the reason. and if you want to capture all by static analysis, i think it's not quite possible.

Comment: Thanks! Question: how do you tokenize a program? Also, I think this code doesn't take into account built-ins such as `int()`?